How to verify that the unit and co-unit of an adjunction form morphisms of functors.
I am studying the concept of adjunctions in category theory and I have trouble wrapping my head around the unit and the co-unit, mainly, verifying that they are morphisms of functors.
Let's just start with what I have gathered so far:
Suppose we have an adjunction $\alpha$ between the functors $F$ and $G$, where $F$ is a functor from categories $\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ and $G$ the other way around.
The unit $\eta$ is then defined as a morphism of functors id$_{\mathcal{C}} \to GF$ where $\eta$ is defined on each $X$ in $\mathcal{C}$ as $\eta_{X}$, which is the image of id$_{FX}$ under $\alpha$. Then $\eta_X$ is a map from $X \to GFX$.
Now I have found that that (somehow) the naturality of $\alpha$ implies that $\eta$ is a morphism of functors but I cannot see why.
What I am basically trying to prove is that $GF f \circ \eta_X = \eta_Y \circ f$ for all $f: X \to Y$ in $\mathcal{C}$. I could really use some directions on this. Thanks.

Welcome to the site. This is a bit confusing to prove for sure, but it gets less confusing once you use the Yoneda philosophy.
We are given $\alpha:\mathcal{D}(FX,Z)\cong\mathcal{C}(X,GZ)$ natural in both $X$ and $Z$. Let's fix $X$. Consider now the natural transformation $\alpha:\mathcal{D}(FX,-)\cong\mathcal{C}(X,G(-))$. Let's call the right hand side the functor $H$. Yoneda tells me this natural transformation is just given by some element of $H(FX)=\mathcal{C}(X,GFX)$; this element is specifically the element $\alpha(1_{FX})=\eta_X$. What does it mean, that $\alpha$ is "given" by $\eta_X$? It means, according to the Yoneda lemma, that $\alpha_Z:\mathcal{D}(FX,Z)\to H(Z)$ takes an arrow $f:FX\to Z$ to the element $H(f)(\eta_X)$. $H(f)$ is just $\mathcal{C}(X,-)(G(f))=G(f)\circ-$ the postcomposition function, so Yoneda tells me that $\alpha(f)=G(f)\circ\eta_X$.
Ok, this is good - I have an explicit formula for what $\alpha$ does. Now to your problem - $GF(f)\circ\eta_X$ is... well, it's just $\alpha(F(f))$, according to the above formula. But hey, now we can use naturality in the other variable, $X$, of the adjunction $\alpha$. Let's name the functor, for fixed $Z\in\mathcal{D}$, $H':=\mathcal{D}(F(-),Z)$; $\alpha$ is also an isomorphism $H'\cong\mathcal{C}(-,GZ)$. I would like to calculate $\alpha(F(f))$, and I can recognise $F(f)$ as $1_{FY}\circ F(f)$ and $H'$ does exactly this, it precomposes with $F(\text{some arrows})$, so it makes sense to define $Z:=FY$, and then $F(f)=H'(f)(1_{FY})$ - hopefully that makes sense.
Now naturality tells me: $$\alpha(F(f))=(\alpha\circ H'(f))(1_{FY})=(\mathcal{C}(-,GFY)(f)\circ\alpha)(1_{FY})=\alpha(1_{FY})\circ f=\eta_Y\circ f$$By definition of $\eta$. But I already know $\alpha(F(f))=GF(f)\circ\eta_X$, so I conclude $GF(f)\circ\eta_X=\eta_Y\circ f$.
There are other ways to do it but I'll leave it at that. So it turns out - assuming you have adjunction isomorphisms $\alpha$ which are natural in the variable $Z\in\mathcal{D}$ - that the adjunction $\alpha$ is natural in the variable $X\in\mathcal{C}$ if and only if $\eta$ is a natural transformation. $F$'s action on arrows is uniquely determined such that $\eta$ is natural, given such an adjunction. There are many equivalent ways to get adjoint functors, and this interested me and confused me in equal measure when I first encountered it.

Thank you so much for the detailed reply. I can follow it for the most part but I am still new to the Yoneda lemma and the part where you use that confuses me. Especially, why specifically is the natural transformation given by the image of $1_{FX}$ and also, how does the Yoneda lemma give us that $f$ gets sent to $H(f)(\eta_X)$. Thanks!

@DueledGalois So both of those follow from the proof / implicit statement of Yoneda’s lemma. But here’s the main point (the same idea which I use later): $\alpha(f)=\alpha(f\circ 1_{FX})=H(f)(\alpha(1_{FX}))=H(f)(\eta_X)$ where the middle step uses naturality and the fact that “composition” is how $\mathcal{D}(FX,-)$ is defined as a functor. When I say it is “given” by $\eta_X$ I’m just being informal, this is the “philosophy”. The precise statement is that $\alpha(f)=H(f)(\eta_X)$. I really recommend Leinster’s “basic category theory” for stuff on adjoints etc.
